# Feeding lots of observations with many binary data features to TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, storage

I have about 1.7 million observations. Each of them has about 4000 boolean features and 4 floating point labels/targets. The features are sparse and approximately homogeneously distributed (about 150 of the 4000 boolean values are set to `True` per observation).

If I store the whole `(1700000, 4000)` matrix as raw numpy file (`npz` format), it takes about 100 MB of disk space. If I load it via `np.load()`, it takes a few minutes and my RAM usage rises by about 7 GB, which is fine on its own.

The problem is, that I have to turn over my boolean values in a `feed_dict` to a `tf.placeholder` in order for the `tf.data.Dataset` to be able to use it. This process takes another 7 GB of RAM. My plan is to collect even more data in the future (might become more than 10 million observations at some point).

**Question:** So how can I feed the data to my DNN (Feed-Forward, dense, ***not*** convolutional and ***not*** recurrent) without creating a bottle-neck and in a way that is native to TensorFlow? I would have thought that this is a pretty standard setting and many people should have that problem – why not? What do I do wrong/different than people without the problem?

---

I heard the [tfrecord format](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tf-records) is [well integrated](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets) with TensorFlow and is able to load lazy but I think it is a bad idea to use that format for my feature structure as it creates one `Message` per observation and saves the features as `map` with the keys of all features as string *per observation*.

Comment: I'm just curious: Do you have an example observation? What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Well.. there are ~140 different entities with ~30 binary properties each. Per scenario (one observation is one scenario) 10 of those ~140 entities will produce one outcome. The 30 properties depend on both, the scenario and the entity, so actually I have a `(10, 30)` matrix of raw data, that I fill with `False` for all unused entities in this scenario, resulting in a `(140, 30)` matrix that I then flatten into the `(4200, 1)` observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, called [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator).

This basically does the trick:

```
def generate_train_data(self, batch_size: int) -> typing.Iterable[typing.Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]]:
    row_id = 0
    features = self.get_features()
    targets = self.get_targets()
    test_amount = self.get_test_data_amount()
    while row_id < features.shape[0]:
        limit = min(features.shape[0] - test_amount, row_id + batch_size)
        feature_batch = features[row_id:limit, :]
        target_batch = targets[row_id:limit, :]
        yield (feature_batch, target_batch)
        del feature_batch, target_batch
        row_id += batch_size
```

And to create the `tf.data.Dataset` something like:

```
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    data.generate_train_data,
    output_types=(tf.bool, tf.bool),
    output_shapes=(
        (None, data.get_feature_amount()),
        (None, data.get_target_amount()),
    ),
    args=(batch_size,),
).repeat()
```

This does of course not shuffle the data yet but that'd be extremely easy to retrofit…